# Why does NMF perform better than LDA on shorter textual inputs

Tags: latent-dirichlet-alloc, non-negative-matrix-factorization

For the reading that I have done, I found that Dirichlet priors typically don't perform well when they aren't given significant amounts of data.

I'm not quite sure why that is. What is it about NMF that allows it to perform well on smaller inputs? Why does the LDA prior perform poorly on smaller data.

Comment: Can you present evidence of this using a sample dataset? I'm not convinced that this is the case, especially if you iterate through the LDA hyperparameters. I would think that requiring both topics and word distributions of topics to be nearly singular (high alpha) would work reasonably well.

Comment: It's from the following article: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-LDA-and-NMF-in-topic-modeling-Under-what-situations-should-we-choose-LDA-or-NMF-Is-there-comparison-of-two-techniques-in-topic-modeling. Can you elaborate on what you mentioned please?